# What is tensorflow concrete function outputs correspond to structured_outputs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, onnx

I trained my customized ssd_mobilenet_v2 using **TensorFlow2 Object Detection API**. 
After training completed, I used exporter_main_v2.py to export a saved_model of my customized model.

If I load saved_model by TensorFlow2, it seem there are two kind of output format.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
saved_model = tf.saved_model.load("saved_model")
detect_fn = saved_model["serving_default"]
print(detect_fn.outputs)
'''
[<tf.Tensor 'Identity:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_1:0' shape=(1, 100, 4) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_2:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_3:0' shape=(1, 100, 7) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_4:0' shape=(1, 100) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_5:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_6:0' shape=(1, 1917, 4) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'Identity_7:0' shape=(1, 1917, 7) dtype=float32>]
'''
print(detect_fn.structured_outputs)
'''
{'detection_classes': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='detection_classes'),
 'detection_scores': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='detection_scores'),
 'detection_multiclass_scores': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100, 7), dtype=tf.float32, name='detection_multiclass_scores'),
 'num_detections': TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, name='num_detections'),
 'raw_detection_boxes': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 1917, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='raw_detection_boxes'),
 'detection_boxes': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='detection_boxes'),
 'detection_anchor_indices': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 100), dtype=tf.float32, name='detection_anchor_indices'),
 'raw_detection_scores': TensorSpec(shape=(1, 1917, 7), dtype=tf.float32, name='raw_detection_scores')}
'''
```

Then, I try to convert this saved_model to onnx format using tf2onnx. 
However, the outputs of onnxruntime was a list. 
By the shape of result in the list, I think that the sequence is same as detect_fn.outputs

```py
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as rt

sess = rt.InferenceSession("model.onnx")
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
pred_onx = sess.run(None, {input_name: np.zeros((1,300,300,3), dtype=np.uint8)})
print(pred_onx) # a list
print([i.shape for i in pred_onx])
'''
[(1, 100),
 (1, 100, 4),
 (1, 100),
 (1, 100, 7),
 (1, 100),
 (1,),
 (1, 1917, 4),
 (1, 1917, 7)]
'''
```

Because there is some shape of result which is same as others, so it become hard to recognized.
Is there any document talk about this relationship that I can refer?

Answer (score 0):

After I looked closely into the values in outputs.
I found the mapping relationship below.

```py
def result_mapper(outputs):
    result_dict = dict()
    result_dict["num_detections"] = outputs[5]
    result_dict["raw_detection_scores"] = outputs[7]
    result_dict["raw_detection_boxes"] = outputs[6]
    result_dict["detection_multiclass_scores"] = outputs[3]
    result_dict["detection_boxes"] = outputs[1]
    result_dict["detection_scores"] = outputs[4]
    result_dict["detection_classes"] = outputs[2]
    result_dict["detection_anchor_indices"] = outputs[0]
    return result_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question and after some hours of stepping through the debugger found they are... in sorted order. The method determining iteration order is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3314df4945518d1157ec748a81ff318b78e29777/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py#L320).

> In the case of dict instances, the sequence consists of the values, sorted by
> key to ensure deterministic behavior.